# Thunar: Failed to open "smb://<address>": The specified location is not supported

Tags: raspberry-pi, archlinux, samba, thunar

I am trying to setup a **NAS** server on my raspberry pi which can be accessed by my home linux machine running **Arch**.

This is my *config* from `/etc/samba/smb.conf` on my raspberry pi

```
[Cloud Pi]
comment = Pi shared folder
path = /home/pi/Shared
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
public = yes
only guest = no
force user = root
force group = root
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
read only = no
```

Ran the following command on my home linux machine to load the smb server

```sh
thunar smb://<IP address>
```

And was greeted with

```
Thunar: Failed to open "smb://<IP address>": The specified location is not supported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were two things I was doing wrong.

### No config file in home linux machine

I had downloaded the `samba` package from **AUR**. On further reading in their [official homepage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samba), they say that post-installation, we need to manually create a default config file at `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

I copied the contents from [here](https://git.samba.org/samba.git/?p=samba.git;a=blob_plain;f=examples/smb.conf.default;hb=HEAD) and pasted it in a new manually created `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file.

### Missing dependencies for Thunar

The following packages were necessary to make it work in my case.

- thunar-shares-plugin
- gvfs-smb

After installing the dependencies, the **first** time I tried to open a file I had to login using my username & password I had used in my raspberry pi while setting up the samba server.

Since then, it works as expected.

Comment: Installing gvfs-smb was all I needed